# What is the most efficient way to get property values from parent object?

Tags: php, class, inheritance

I have a single instance parent class, which holds 'local global properties', that every child class should have access to (also when it is changed)

I can think of two ways to make sure a child from an instantiated parent inherits the parent values:

1) Using static variables

```
class p
{
public static $var = 0;
}

class c extends p
{
function foo()
{
echo parent::$var;
}
}

$p = new p;
$c = new c;

$c->foo(); //echoes 0
p::$var = 2;
$c->foo(); //echoes 2
```

2) Using passed object

```
    class p
    {
          public $var = 0;
    }

    class c extends p
    {
           function update_var(p $p)
      {
            $this->var = $p->var;
      }

    function foo()
    {
    echo $this->var;
    }
    }

    $p = new p;
    $c = new c;

    $c->foo(); //echoes 0
    $p->var = 2;
$c->update_var($p);
    $c->foo(); //echoes 2
```

In my opinion the static solution is by far the most elegant one, but there might be some drawbacks, that I'm not seeing. Which solution do you believe to be the best, or is there a third better option?

(Also note, in this example the $var is public to make this example easier to illustrate, but will end up protected)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> that every child class should have access to (also when it is changed)

This means that you want to use static variables, since this is exactly what they were designed for.

Another option would be to use constants, but if they fit neatly in your class, that `static` is the way to go

Edit: Or, you could use the pattern @true suggested if you need something a bit more complex.

Comment: Thank you very much. That was also the solution I hoped would be the right one :)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it's better to have different object as storage for those variables, that could be injected to every object?

Idea with updating variables seems to be crazy.

If you need less code, you can do this with static vars, but I would do some config container, that will be injected in every class (read about dependency injection: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)

```
class Config
{
    protected $vars;

    public function __get($name)
    {
        if (isset($this->vars[$name])) {
            return $this->$name;
        }
    }

    public function __set($name, $value)
    {
        return $this->vars[$name] = $value;
    }

    public function toArray()
    {
        return $this->vars;
    }
}

class Component 
{
    protected $config;

    public function __construct(Config $config = null)
    {
        $this->config = $config;
    }

    public function getConfig()
    {
        return $this->config;
    }
}

// Create config instance
$config = new Config();

// Store variable
$config->testVar = 'test value';

// Create component and inject config
$component = new Component($config);

// Save another one variable in config
$config->test2Var = 'test 2 value';

// Create one more component and inject config
$component2  = new Component($config);

// Create one more varible
$config->someMoreVar = 'another one variable';

// Check configs in different components, values will be same (because config object is not cloned, just link to this object is saved in Component's $config property):
var_dump($component->getConfig()->toArray());
var_dump($component2->getConfig()->toArray());
```

P.S. I've not tested this code, just to show an idea

Comment: Would you use this to store all config values for all parent classes? Or make a config class for each parent class? I have several parent classes, that each have multiple 'global' properties to pass on, and the parent classes shouldn't really have access to other parent classes config properties.

Comment: But I do like the idea of having all config values in the same place. Maybe I could do some sort of authentication, to make sure the right classes only have access to the right properties...

Comment: Currently in my projects i use DI with __get __set methods, so i can access config from any object using $this->config call.

Comment: My point though, is that I might not want any object to have access to all config properties. But thanks for the alternative solution, I'll need to think a bit more about this, before settling it.